# TV stream and VPN

Tags: tv, openvpn

I'm trying to see a Spanish TV channel by Internet from Germany, but nor with a Spanish proxy and neither through VPN can I see this channel. I work with Ubuntu 12.10 and

This live TV channel can be seen in [this](http://www.youtube.com/user/ONDACADIZTV/featured) youtube channel. If you try to play it from outside of Spain you can see a message saying: "this video isn't available".

Main question: how can I "get" a message saying the "technical" reason I can't to play it?

Secondary question: what is the diference between a TV channel (stream) and other type of "internet" service? I mean, why VPN works satisfactorily with other internet services but not with TV?

Answer (score 1):

I can hardly understand your question but any site you visit through a VPN will see the VPN server's IP address (which probably is used for determining the geographical location). Try connecting to a different VPN server in a different country. If the VPN service you are subscribing to doesn't have one in the country you want, I recommend switching services. [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) is an example of a VPN service that has servers around the world.